# WPF GUI not updating although main thread is running

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a Textbox with Binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TestString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Here the TestString implementation:

```
    private string testString;
    public string TestString
    {
        get { return testString; }
        set
        {
            if (testString != value)
            {
                testString = value;
                PropChanged(); // INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation ..
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
```

The set method of the TestString Property needs a couple of milliseconds (e.g. you can test it with a Sleep of 100ms), then if you hold down a letter key, you first see the update of the edit with a couple of letters and then the GUI stops updating / refreshing all the time you hold down a letter key. If the key is released, the gui continues updating.

I know that for long running actions I should use asynchronous programming mechanisms, but the annoying thing is, I don't exactly know whats the threshold when WPF starts not updating any more.
I personally don't want to implement the asynchronous overhead for short actions that last 5 or 10 or 100ms, because the UI is still responsive enough (if WPF would update ...).

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix this without using asynchronous programming?

In the Borland VCL (and in WinForms I guess) this isn't a problem at all because the GUI is updating after each key event.

By the way if you use a slider there are a lot more UI mousemove events than a holded key, and WPF has no problem updating the GUI if you use a slider, even if the operation in the ui thread lasts very long (the only thing is that the ui reacts more slow).

Comment: please, show implementation of `TestString` property

Answer (score 1):

Don't put any synchronous logic inside your setter. Normally I would not recommend putting logic inside your setter at all, but when you do - do it asynchronously. Otherwise your UI will get blocked as you have described.

```
 private string _testString;

public string TestString
{
    get { return _testString; }
    set
    {
        // Custom Method, returns true if property has changed
        if (SetProperty(ref _testString, value))
        {
            DoSomeStuff();
        }
    }
}

private async void DoSomeStuff()
{
    // Do long lasting calls here
    await Task.Delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: Of course I could ... but I would like to know why this happens.
And how do I know if the action is too long for a setter ?
Thanks anyway for your answer !

Comment: It would be interesting what kind of logic you put into the setter. Every "long lasting" operation which is executed on the Main Thread (UI Thread) freezes your UI. How you defined a "long lasting task" is your definition. Normally service calls, calculation, database access etc.

Comment: I do a calculation which is fast enough (as I wrote, some milliseconds) so there would be no need for a task and all the synchronization stuff which is then needed. I Still have no clue why WPF stops rendering.

Answer (score 0):

main thread (UI thread) in wpf is basically nothing else that infinite loop. The loop basically does this:

1. process all events; 2. render ui; 1. process all events; 2. render ui, etc..

So when you press key, it fires an event and changes text in checkbox. The wpf databinding then changes the `TestStrin`g property and after all is done, UI is rendered

Now, the loop repeats. First step is to process all events. But since the previous cycle took longer, there is a lot of events to process (the events are buffered somewhere). Multiple events changes the TestString property multiple times before the UI renders. So this cycle took event more than the first one and the next one will have to process even more events and your UI thread is flooded with event handlers.

So how much time do you have in one cycle of loop? Well wrong question. Among others, it depends on client's PC settings and how fast is his keyboards (how often is the key repeated, when you press and hold it).

You should write you code such way, that even the event is fired multipe times, you don't flood UI thread with your event handling.

**EDIT:**
You may be interested in [Binding.Delay](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/21/wpf-4-5-part-4-the-new-bindings-delay-property/) property. For example delay 100ms tells WPF to update the binding source (TestString in this case) at most 10x per second, event if the `TextBox.Text` has changed 25x times.

Another solution is `Reactive Extensions` library. It basically helps you to deal with events using linq like operators. For example:

```
Observable.FromEvent<PropertyChangedEventArs)(this, nameof(PropertyChanged))
  .Where(e => e.PropertyName == nameof(TestString))
  .Sample(TimeSpan.FromMiliseconds(100))
  .Subscribe(() => Thread.Sleep(...))
```